# Are my JsonConvert.DeserailizeObject parameters correct?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I am creating a xamarin application that puts in a request to a rest api. I have been following tutorials and it all seems to be in order, but when I get to JsonConvert.DeserializeObjects, then it throws an error.

My main question is, are my classes and my http requests set up correctly?

Here are my classes for the json made from json2csharp

```
    public class Results
    {
        public int skip { get; set; }
        public int limit { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
    }

    public class Meta
    {
        public string disclaimer { get; set; }
        public string terms { get; set; }
        public string license { get; set; }
        public string last_updated { get; set; }
        public Results results { get; set; }
    }

    public class Openfda
    {
        public List<string> product_ndc { get; set; }
        public List<bool> is_original_packager { get; set; }
        public List<string> package_ndc { get; set; }
        public List<string> generic_name { get; set; }
        public List<string> spl_set_id { get; set; }
        public List<string> brand_name { get; set; }
        public List<string> manufacturer_name { get; set; }
        public List<string> unii { get; set; }
        public List<string> rxcui { get; set; }
        public List<string> spl_id { get; set; }
        public List<string> substance_name { get; set; }
        public List<string> product_type { get; set; }
        public List<string> route { get; set; }
        public List<string> application_number { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string effective_time { get; set; }
        public List<string> spl_unclassified_section_table { get; set; }
        public List<string> contraindications { get; set; }
        public List<string> precautions { get; set; }
        public List<string> warnings { get; set; }
        public List<string> description { get; set; }
        public List<string> spl_product_data_elements { get; set; }
        public Openfda openfda { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public List<string> dosage_and_administration { get; set; }
        public List<string> adverse_reactions { get; set; }
        public List<string> spl_unclassified_section { get; set; }
        public List<string> how_supplied_table { get; set; }
        public List<string> how_supplied { get; set; }
        public List<string> package_label_principal_display_panel { get; set; }
        public List<string> indications_and_usage { get; set; }
        public List<string> clinical_pharmacology { get; set; }
        public string set_id { get; set; }
        //public string id { get; set; }
        public List<string> overdosage { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Meta meta { get; set; }
        public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is my code to create the call to the actual API

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


        var baseURI = new Uri("https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.package_ndc:" + pullText.Text + "&limit=1");

        client.BaseAddress = baseURI;

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage resp = client.GetAsync(baseURI).Result;

        var dataObjects = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        var otherView = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Openfda>("{\"results\":[\"openfda\":{\"product_ndc\":");
```

Comment: actually your input string is not in same format as `serialize string` of  `OpenFda`, if you create `JObject` of your input string, and then pass `jObj["results"]["openfda"]` to your `DeserializeObject` method it will work for you.

Comment: First of all, there are only keys in `{\"results\":[\"openfda\":{\"product_ndc\":` json string. and it should be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here are my classes for the json made from json2csharp

When you use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/), you should deserialize json string to `RootObject` because that tool generate class from json string you entered and maps all the objects. `RootObject` is main object in your json string.

```
var otherView = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("YOUR_JSON_STRING");
```

Comment: RootObject should just be a placeholder for whatever you ultimately name your class, otherwise you’re going to end up with multiple conflicting RootObject’s for different payloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for your output,

```
 var otherView = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("{\"results\":[\"openfda\":{\"product_ndc\":");
 foreach( var item in otherView.Result)
 {
           // item.Openfda
  }
```